# Hibernate Native SQL Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have my Native SQL statement like this:

SQLQuery:

```
select Name ,Id,COUNT(ID) from Employee;
```

Employee HBM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="edu.model.Master" table="test_prefixmaster">
        <id name="empcode" column="EMPCODE" length="10" ></id>

        <property name="empname">
            <column name="NAME" length="30" />
        </property>
    </class>
    <sql-query name="SQLQuery" callable="true">
    <return alias="emp" class="edu.model.Employee">
        <return-property name="empid" column="EMPID" />
        <return-property name="empname" column="EMPNAME" />
        </return>
        </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In MyTest Class:

```
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery("SQLQuery");
    List emp=new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < emp.size(); i++) {                  
    Employee emp = (Employee) emp.get(i);
    System.out.println("Employee Id:::" + emp.getEmpId());
   System.out.println("Employee Name:::" + emp.getEmpname());
//I want to get here System.out.println("Employee Count");
}
```

How can I map and print the Employee count also in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery("SQLQuery");
    List empList=new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < empList.size(); i++) {                  
    Employee emp = (Employee) empList.get(i);
    System.out.println("Employee Code:::" + emp.getEmpcode());
   System.out.println("Employee Name:::" + emp.getEmpname());

//I want to get here System.out.println("Employee Count");
   System.out.println("Employee Count:::" + empList.size());
}
```

for Distinct Employee

change your query

```
select Name ,distinct (Id) from Employee ;
```

Comment: In my Query the Employee ID's will get Repeated ,I want to find the count for particular employee?

Comment: I'had shown here a simple Query,but My Query If i execute on MySQL command prompt,It is returning Count of a Particula Employee?I want to run the same with Hibernate?

Comment: you can find my Query here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212488/how-to-write-hibernate-mapping-file-and-sql-mapping-for-mysql-storedprocedure                          your answer will return all list size ,but that is not actual requirement

Comment: How do I get that into my Employee Model class,how can I refer(emp.getEmpCode etc...) the distict(Id) through emp reference?

Comment: added distinct class on id column only, it will still refference to id column in Model class. Thing is it will return Unique Emplooye objects , then we are calling size on List.

Comment: I want my Count to print on emp(Employee) reference?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you've chosen as the best answer serves your purpose correctly. But if you want the count of the ID from the query you need to add another property in your entity class as empIdCount and map the count value to it. This will slove your purpose. You can directly get the count of the EmpIds.